# Permissions & Settings in Profile and Permission Set and its Usage

Tags: user, lightning-experience, permission-sets, custom-profile, salesforce-classic

I just came across the below 2 scenario regarding the Salesforce Classic & Lightning experience Enable/Disable for a user via Profile and  Permission Set once the Lightning Feature is enabled.

[image]

**Scenario 1)** Enabled 'Lightning Experience User' flag in Custom profile Level and disabled the  same 'Lightning Experience User' flag in Permission Set assigned to particular user.

**Scenario 2)** This is the vice-versa of above scenario, Disabled 'Lightning Experience User' flag in Custom profile Level and Enabled the  same 'Lightning Experience User' flag in Permission Set assigned to particular user.

In both case I got the same results as the user able to get the switch to/back option from lightning/Classic Experience.

So Is this means that there is **`"No"`** **Order or Sequence** in which Permission Set Assignment of an Option/Feature will ***override*** the same option/Feature in Profile. Or Vice versa.

- Scenario 1 takeaway - If a feature is enabled in profile Level it will be available for all users under it even though if a specific user disabled it via Permission set for him explicitly.
- Scenario 2 takeaway - If a feature is disabled in profile Level it won't be available for all users under it except the specific user who explicitly enable it via Permission set.

Can you please share some thoughts on this especially on Scenario 1 and its outcome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Rule of thumb is permission set extend the access of profile and do not restrict.

1.In first scenario since profile already has access which means permission set cannot disable as permission sets are meant to extend the behaviour

2.Second case its obvious .

If you want to restrict the behaviour for a user ,then disable at profile and do not assign any permission set that provides access to the lightning experience while assign permission set to users needing the functionality

Comment: Thx for the details.. That clear the doubt for me.. But jst need to reaffirm  this, I have one more question on this. Since Permission set contains the same set of Permissions & settings similar in Profile, the above mentioned scenarios & answer/rule will be applied in all cases & not just in Lightning Experience User flag, Is it? When Profiles & Permission Set used together, Permission Set can extend the access of profile & not restrict.

Comment: That's correct .It's general rule with permission sets .It cannot restrict and it extends access